# Hide items outside of visible area

Tags: javascript

I lazily load the items (gifs) on my page. The script I have works fine. But I'd also like to hide them (`display:none;`) when they're outside of visible area. My lazyload script:

```
refresh_handler = function(e) {
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("*[realsrc]");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
       var boundingClientRect = elements[i].getBoundingClientRect();
       if (elements[i].hasAttribute("realsrc") && boundingClientRect.top < window.innerHeight) {
           elements[i].setAttribute("src", elements[i].getAttribute("realsrc"));
           elements[i].removeAttribute("realsrc");
       }
   }
};

window.addEventListener('scroll', refresh_handler);
window.addEventListener('load', refresh_handler);
window.addEventListener('resize', refresh_handler);
```

What I tried in order to hide them is adding a condition within the `for` loop:

```
if (boundingClientRect.top > window.innerHeight) {
elements[i].getAttribute("src").style.display="none";
}
```

This last part doesn't work. I don't get why?

Any idea?

Comment: did you try? : elements[i].style.display="none";

Comment: I think that the best way to do it is basiclly use CSS.
you can give your area Overflow: hidden;
and all the elements that outside that area will not be visiable.

Comment: why are you using .getAttribute("src").style.....?

Comment: Please attach a JSFiddle in your post

Comment: @PiotrMirosz I've tried but it doesn't work. The elements do not lazy-load anymore :(

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the

```
if (boundingClientRect.top > window.innerHeight) {
    elements[i].getAttribute("src").style.display="none";
}
```

with

```
if (boundingClientRect.top > window.innerHeight) {
    elements[i].style.display="none";  // this will hide the element 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this but then the lazyload doesn't work anymore :( Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

***I suggest looking into [jquery-visible](https://github.com/customd/jquery-visible). Check out the [demo](http://opensource.teamdf.com/visible/examples/demo-basic.html).*** And of course looking at my code snippet. Maybe that's the right way to go (for you). Anyways, I hope it was helpful. **:)**

```js
$.fn.isInViewport = function() {
  var elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
  var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();

  var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

  return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
};

$(window).on('resize scroll', function() {
  $('.color').each(function() {
      var activeColor = $(this).attr('id');
    if ($(this).isInViewport()) {
      $('#fixed-' + activeColor).addClass(activeColor + '-active');
    } else {
      $('#fixed-' + activeColor).removeClass(activeColor + '-active');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.fixed-red,
.fixed-green,
.fixed-blue {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  background: #333;
}

.fixed-green {
  top: 50px;
}

.fixed-blue {
  top: 90px;
}

.red-active {
  background: #f00;
}

.green-active {
  background: #0f0;
}

.blue-active {
  background: #00f;
}

.color {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#red {
  background: #900;
  text-align: center;
  font-size:3rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#green {
  background: #090;
  text-align: center;
  font-size:3rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: yellow;
}

#blue {
  background: #009;
  text-align: center;
  font-size:3rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fixed-red" class="fixed-red red-active"></div>
<div id="fixed-green" class="fixed-green"></div>
<div id="fixed-blue" class="fixed-blue"></div>
<div id="red" class="color">Viewport 1</div>
<div id="green" class="color">Viewport 2</div>
<div id="blue" class="color">Viewport 3</div>
```